# How to use an enum as an interface in Typsecript?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface

I am trying to define an enum but also use it as an interface. My current code makes two identical objects, an enum and an interface. How can I combine them?

```
interface MyIface {
  alice: 'Alice',
  bob: 'Bob'
}

enum MyEnum {
  alice = 'Alice'
  bob = 'Bob'
}
```

Throughout the code, I want to be able to enforce the type for a param and I also want to be able to use the enum, like so:

```
function myFunc(params: MyIface) {}

const myVar = MyEnum.alice
```

How can I do this succinctly? Ideally, I just have the following:

```
enum MyCombinedObject {
  alice = 'Alice'
  bob = 'Bob'
}

function myFunc(params: MyCombinedObject) {}

const myVar = MyCombinedObject.alice
```

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/WKyopN) is how I might implement what you're talking about, but your `MyIface` is a weird type... all values of `MyIface` need to serialize to `{"alice":"Alice","bob":"Bob"}`, so I don't see why you'd ever be passing it around to functions.  Seems like a single value of that type would suffice everywhere.  Could you demonstrate how `myFunc()` is supposed to work? (Both from the caller's side and from the implementer's side?)

Comment: The example might be too contrived: here  `params: MyIface` means that params is `{ alice: 'Alice', bob: 'Bob' }` with these exact values; wheareas `params: MyCombinedObject` means that params can be one of the enum values.